# Is it possible to automatically match rows in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

Let's say, that I have the following table:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | B |
| B | C | C |
| C | D | E |

Is there any automatic method to match rows in those three columns? Expected result looks like this:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A |  |
| B |  | B |
| C | C | C |
|  | D |  |
|  |  | E |

Comment: Are there any duplicate values in any of the columns?

Comment: @FlexYourData No, values are unique.

Comment: What version of Excel? Is it 2019 or do you have O365 available?

Comment: @FlexYourData 2019.

Comment: What is the data?  Is it predetermined? Is it numerical?  e.g. It is letters A-z but not all are present in each set. e.g. it is totally random data. e.g. it is text. etc. ?

Comment: @BlindSpots It is text and the properties are exactly as in presented case: not every text shows in every column. To simplify, I'm looking for an equivalent of SQL's FULL OUTER JOIN for a set of columns in Excel (if possible).